# Column can not be null error while joining derived table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Here is my sql query:

```
select
  t1.id, t1.text as text, l.likes as likecount
from
  table1 as t1 left join (select feed_id, count(user_id) as likes
                          from likes
                          where feed_id=12345) l
  on t1.id=l.feed_id where t1.id=12345
```

This query simply gets one particular entry with how many people likes that entry. In this example entry number 12345. When a entry have at least 1 like, this query is working fine. But when I run this query for an entry with no likes, its giving error that column feed is can not be null.

The reason of this error is that inner query is returning a row with feed_id null and likes 0 which is creating problem in joining tables. Another interesting factor is that this thing is working file on my local server but not on my live server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use only one WHERE clause:

```
select
  t1.id, t1.text as text, l.likes as likecount
from
  table1 as t1 left join (select feed_id, count(user_id) as likes
                          from likes
                          group by feed_id) l
  on t1.id=l.feed_id
where t1.id=12345
```

You don't need it in your subquery, but you need yo use a GROUP BY clause instead.

But you probably can simplify your query above using just this:

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t1.text, COUNT(DISTINCT likes.user_id) likecount
FROM
  table1 as t1 LEFT JOIN likes
  ON t1.id = likes.feed_id
WHERE
  t1.id = 12345
```

Comment: the `WHERE` in the subquery is fine syntactically, and it may even be preferable for performance as it will limit the number of rows returned by the subquery.

Comment: @EdGibbs really need to see the execution plans to say for sure. Dropping the subquery altogether and moving to fthiella's second script would definitely improve performance.

Comment: @whytheq - I absolutely agree. The second query is superior. A correlated subquery would work too (`SELECT t1.id, t1.text, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE t1.id = likes.feed_id) likecount ...`) but I tend to reach for those as a last resort rather than a first.

Comment: @EdGibbs if the filter is definitely on the first table `WHERE  t1.id = 12345` then may aswell change the second query to an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @whytheq - I don't know about that. If there are no corresponding `likes` rows with `feed_id = 12345` you'd get "no results" rather than "results with a count of zero".

Comment: No worries - I've had more than my share of those :)

Comment: @EdGibbs the second query says `WHERE t1.id = 12345`....if 12345 does not exist in t1 then `SELECT t1.id, t1.text` won't be returning anything even when using a `LOJ`

Comment: You're right that if 12345 isn't in `t1` the inner join is harmless. The problem comes in when 12345 is in `t1` but *not* in `likes`. If you inner join in that situation you'll get nothing.

Comment: @EdGibbs wow...I'm really trying to convince myself I'm right about this one! You're comment is spot on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `group by feed_id` to your inner query:

```
select
  t1.id, t1.text as text, l.likes as likecount
from
  table1 as t1 left join (select feed_id, count(user_id) as likes
                          from likes
                          where feed_id=12345
                          group by feed_id) l
  on t1.id=l.feed_id where t1.id=12345
```